# Rails unless puts another value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails loop with many values, what's the best method of doing something like:

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
<%= r.title, unless r.title.blank? puts 'N/A' %>
<%= r.year, unless r.year.blank? puts 'N/A' %>
<%= r.description, unless r.description.blank? puts 'N/A' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= r.title.presence || 'N/A' %>
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like

```
r.title.presence || 'N/A'
```

You should not use `puts` here. `puts` is for writing to `stdout`.

Comment: He is checking `blank?`. Your solution will not work when the title is a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.title.presence || 'N/A' %>
  <%= r.year.presence || 'N/A' %>
  <%= r.description.presence || 'N/A' %>
<% end %>
```

You may also want to have a look to the [Draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).